# Using Stripe payment for accepting Donations in iOS app

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

Can i use a third part library like "Stripe" to accept Donations (charity) payments in my iOS app? Will my app pass the Apple review team? or it will be rejected? What is the proper way to accept Donations in my iOS app?
Thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [App Store's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) define what's acceptable and what's not regarding charities & donations. Furthermore, it describes how to [become an approved nonprofit](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-nonprofits/).

> 3.2.1 Acceptable
>
> (vi) Approved nonprofits may fundraise directly within their own apps or third-party apps, provided those fundraising campaigns adhere to all App Review Guidelines and offer Apple Pay support. These apps must disclose how the funds will be used, abide by all required local and federal laws, and ensure appropriate tax receipts are available to donors. Additional information shall be provided to App Review upon request. Nonprofit platforms that connect donors to other nonprofits must ensure that every nonprofit listed in the app has also gone through the nonprofit approval process. Learn more about becoming an [approved nonprofit](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-nonprofits/).

> 3.2.2 Unacceptable
>
> (iv) Unless you are an approved nonprofit or otherwise permitted under Section 3.2.1 (vi) above, collecting funds within the app for charities and fundraisers. Apps that seek to raise money for such causes must be free on the App Store and **may only collect funds outside of the app, such as via Safari or SMS.**

Answer (score 0):

In the US if you don't have an EIN and you are not a charity but you are just seeking private donations it will likely be rejected. I would use another avenue, a web link to your own website could be included in the description of the app link or u can include a "pro" version of your app as a way, users can download the free version for free and upgrade for a couple bucks. I don't think I have seen non-incorporated entities seeking donation get approved if they placed it into a native app, as this could lead to abuse (imo)